# java hash map thread visibility

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am fully loading a java HashMap on initialization, but after initialization multiple threads will be reading the data from the HashMap.  i'd like to avoid any type of synchronization since the map is essentially read only and never changes.   But can i guarantee that all keys and values are visible to all threads?

Comment: Java always surprises me, but why should any key be hidden from any thread? Unless the threads are fired before the init of the map?

Comment: @Santiago, it's not java, it's the hardware :). Due to out of order writes and CPU caches some writes may not reach the other CPU and you can stale writes; on a side note what John V says it's all good

Comment: Easiest AND straightforward way to do it is final field map w/ an extra method `Map<K,V> createMap(){}` and call in the c-tor. Even if the field is not final, most probably the object is going to be made available/visible to other threads by a volatile variable (queue/exchanger) or any happens-before semantics, so in the end it won't matter.

Comment: if it's a `static` field, you are fine. see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the map's contents never change then you don't have a problem. Memory model visibility problems come into play only when the contents of a variable change.

You will likely want to synchronize the initialization of the map both to make sure no threads access it before it's fully initialized, and to make sure that the values loaded into the map are all visible.

EDIT: Originally I totally ignored the issue of how the map gets initialized in the first place. After reading [one of the Pugh articles](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html) (again) it seems like the map really needs to be final in order for the initialization-data to become visible:

> The ability to see the correctly constructed value for the field is nice, but if the field itself is a reference, then you also want your code to see the up to date values for the object (or array) to which it points. If your field is a final field, this is also guaranteed. So, you can have a final pointer to an array and not have to worry about other threads seeing the correct values for the array reference, but incorrect values for the contents of the array. Again, by "correct" here, we mean "up to date as of the end of the object's constructor", not "the latest value available".

There is a list of conditions that force a 'happens-before' relationship, given in the Java spec, I should quote them here (or if somebody else does in their answer I will vote for it). The static variable and Holder idiom is certainly one way to go. The question is pretty broad as it doesn't specify how the map gets initialized, if you post a question describing how you propose to do the initialization you will likely get a more directly helpful answer.

Comment: Unless specifically specified by synchronization or volatile, it was my understanding that the JMM could use register or cpu specific cache and not flush to main memory.  I don't believe java HashMap uses volatile or synchronization.  So how can you be sure the values are visible to other threads?

Comment: This may not be true, according to the memory model I would think there is no garuntee (happens before ordering) with the final put of a hashmap and its initial read.  Any reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: @richs: that's why I added that you want the initialization to be synchronized, you want to make sure your initial values are visible and the synchronization will force that. After initialization though, as long as no further changes are made to the map, there's no reason for the cache and memory to differ.

Comment: But even with the synchronization wouldn't threads be able to see a partially initialized HashMap?  Say Thread A starts to initialize the HashMap, at time 1 the Map is created time 2-10 the HashMap is being added to.  At time 3 Thread B comes in, see's the Map is initialized and as a result all add's after time 3 aren't visible.  Pugh goes into detail about something like this in his memory model I linked.  And when I say 'with synchroninzation'  I mean youre not synchronizing on the read of the hashmap.

Comment: @John V: but in the case of the OP's question there are no more adds by the time thread B can get in.

Comment: If all the adds are happening in the constructor, and the HashMap isn't final, according to what Pugh says in his paper - The instance of the object can become visible and the puts of the HashMap (even if in the constructor) do not need to be visible to anyone at any specific point (even with one side synchronization).  So if another thread comes in and reads a constructed HashMap they may not see the initial puts.  It would be a similar issue to the classic Lazy Initialization bug.

Comment: i think we're good as long as all initialization is done before any other thread accesses the HashMap.  Initialization will flush to main memory and then all other threads will go to main memory to get their initial instance of the HashMap.  After that everything is fine because  no more changes will occur on the Map.

Comment: John V: yeah, there are possible ways to go wrong. the OP doesn't specify how the map is initialized or published.

Comment: @richs: I think John V's point is there is no flush to main memory if no one is using the lock but the initializing thread.

Comment: So are you saying that synchronizing the HashMap initialization won't guarantee that the HashMap is visible to other threads.

Comment: Sorry so reading your edit it seems the field only needs to be final and there is no need to use synchronization.

Comment: @irreputable, I dont want to break the party but accessing/initializing other classes during `<clinit>`  (or `static{}`) the field `map` NOT be properly initialized. It is true that after finishing the static initializer quite a few synchronized blocks would be released (thus everything visible) but it's possible to make that the static field is accessed earlier.

Comment: @bestsss true, but I'd still consider that *thread* safe. logic problems within a thread is not the subject here.

Comment: @irreputable dunno, classloading with multiple threads has been a major issue in java for almost a decade. the #1 bug in java: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4670071

Comment: @bestsss per language spec it should be thread safe - another thread cannot access the static field until the class is initialized. If you argue that the spec is bad, that it cannot be properly implemented (correct, fast, concurrent), then we are on a whole different subject.

Comment: @Nathan Just to give more background, I'm fully loading the HashMap in the constructor.  So based on the JMM article ( http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html) you referenced, I believe that making the HashMap final and fully loading in the constructor will make all references in the HashMap visible to all threads.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the HashMap declared as final, and you pre-initialize a local HashMap then store the global HashMap with the local, after constructor initialization that HashMap's contents are garunteed to be visibile.

> Final fields must be used correctly to
>   provide a guarantee of immutability.
>   An object is considered to be
>   completely initialized when its
>   constructor finishes. A thread that
>   can only see a reference to an object
>   after that object has been completely
>   initialized is guaranteed to see the
>   correctly initialized values for that
>   object’s final fields.

http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Using [ImmutableMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) from Guava would be the best solution.

Comment: +1 This gives a solid guarantee, that threads can not brake your code at that part.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the safe way is to declare it final and initialize it in a constructor: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_final.shtml

Comment: @SLaks, what the guy says it's true, though. In java a final field must be readily visible to other threads, if 'this' reference doesn't escape during c-tor call. So the answer is correct as long it's firstly filled then assigned.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to synchronize the map if all threads just read it. To ensure immutability I would transform the Map into an unmodifiable Map after initialization:

```
map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
```

If a thread calls an operation which would modify the Map an `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown instead.

Comment: While the answer is wrong per se (it doesn't make sure the content will be visible) `UnmodifiableMap` class has it's delegate Map final, so it will work, albeit still it's an impl. detail.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the initialization is complete before reading starts there is no reason why all the contents of the HashMap would not be visible to every thread.

Comment: that's not true, w/o final/volatile writes, the content may stay in the CPU cache and there is no guarantee it will be visible. Handling the object to make it visible to other threads will most likely be done via some volatile/sync. code, though. So the invariants will be seen properly.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the correct answer.**

I bet your map is a static field, then yes, it's safe to read it without sync.

```
class SomeClass
    static Map map = init();
```

This is because JVM does an implicit double-checked locking for class initialization.

Basically, you want a singleton. There are several technics, and using static field is one of them. I bet your map is a "global" thing, so naturally it's a static field, therefore thread safe.

There are cases when a lazily initialized data structure is not global, so we need other singleton implementation schemes, including eager synchronization, volatile reference, or through an intermediary final reference. see wikipedia on Double-checked locking